# jquery-ui tabs with fadeIn?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, fadein

I have a small JQuery Tabs widget in a sidebar that fades in when the page loads, discreetly calling attention to itself and the interesting content behind the tabs.

To build on this effect it might be nice if the individual tabs could fade in one after the other.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tabs are just `li` elements, can you set all of them to `display:none` when you first load the page, and then use JQuery's `Fade` (http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) effect to individually fade each `li` element in?

Comment: Simply listing calls to fadeIn("slow") on each element results in all fading in at the same time. I don't know how to control the timing in order to delay an element's fade until the previous one is complete.

Comment: A possibly messy way to do it might be to use fadeIn's callback function and use nested fadeIn's. The callback isn't called until the animation is complete, so the each successive fadeIn wouldn't be called until the previous one is complete.

Another (possibly messy) option is to use some kind of Javascript sleep() timer.

Comment: The callback idea sounds good. Messy in an elegant sort of way. Will try tomorrow - it's 1am here. Thanks!

Comment: we say "la nuit porte conseils" and upon waking I thought maybe "sleep" was the answer after all. I credit you for suggesting it!

Answer (score 6):

This will make when select the tab desappear, and when it is shown appear!

```
$('.tabs').tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).animate({opacity:0.1});
        },
        show: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.panel).animate({opacity:1.0},1000);
        }
});
```

Comment: VERY NICE CODE MAN ITS WORKING VERY GOOD FOR THE FADEIN EFFECT

Answer (score 0):

I found a discussion of my problem here: http://p.karageorgakis.com/blog/jquery_simulating_a_delay_function_between_fade_in_out_effects/

Among the solutions proposed, the javascript `setTimeout()` trumped the other solutions, at least for my purpose.

Here is the code I went with:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tabs").fadeIn(500);
    $("#li1").fadeIn(500);
    setTimeout('$("#li2").fadeIn(500)', 300);
    setTimeout('$("#li3").fadeIn(500)', 600);
    setTimeout('$("#li4").fadeIn(500)', 900);
});
```

The tabs widget itself as well as the list items are all set to `display:none` at the outset.

There was another issue that I will share, because it led me to the nice fade solution.

This widget needed to float to the left of some other content, but also needed to be hidden until fully instantiated by JQuery. `fadeIn()` wasn't working with an element set to `visibility:hidden`; it had to be `display:none`, but this caused the widget to displace the surrounding content and appear abruptly, which looked really awful. Fading in was a way to mitigate that.

In retrospect, maybe I could block off the (known) dimensions of the tabs widget, anyway I like the result I got!